# Change UI size based on statictext Extendscript

Tags: javascript, extendscript

I have the following code:

```
var win = new Window('palette');
var textGroup = win.add("group");
var text = textGroup.add("statictext{text:''}");
var button = textGroup.add("button{text: 'Add text'}");

button.onClick = function()
{
    text.text += "new line\n";
}
```

How can I force the window size(or textgroup size), to fit the new text size while I add new lines to the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found how, I needed to resize the text and then call window layout():

```
button.onClick = function()
{
    text.text += "new line\n";
    text.size.height += text.graphics.font.size;
    text.window.layout.layout(true)   
}
```